# N2CMS TinyMCE filter_allowed_protocols for skype:{user}?call

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce, n2, n2cms

I am using N2CMS (2.2.1.1) and I have a simple TextPart that I am trying to enter a skype button into which contains a link with the following url ( skype:{user}?call ).

I am entering this into the "HTML" editor (not the wysiwyg editor) and every time i click update, tinymce is rewriting the URL to "/N2/Content/skype:{user}?call" which is causing a "dangerous request" exception and more importantly is not working to make a skype call.

I know I need to tell TinyMCE that "skype:" is an allowed protocol, but in the new version of N2CMS the N2 installation runs from a zip - I'm unsure how/where to tell TinyMCE to allow the skype: protocol in url's. I especially want to keep from modifying the zip so that in the future it is not a PITA to update N2CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although N2CMS in latest versions uses ZIP archive as a default storage for its files, TinyMCE settings should still be in the same place where they always were - in web.config.

Here is brief example of how to add values

```
<n2>
    <edit>
         <tinyMCE enabled="true" cssUrl="/UI/CSS/editor.css">
              <settings>
                   <add key="theme_advanced_blockformats" value="h1,h2,h3" />
```

Put me on the right track, the exact answer; however, is:

```
  <n2 xmlns="http://n2cms.com/schemas/configuration/v3">    
    <edit>
      <tinyMCE enabled="true">
        <settings>
          <add key="convert_urls" value="false" />
        </settings>
      </tinyMCE>
    </edit>
  </n2>
```

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the correct track - the exact answer for anyone else looking is as follows

      <tinyMCE enabled="true">
        <settings>
          <add key="convert_urls" value="false" />
        </settings>
      </tinyMCE>
    </edit>