# tinyMCE meddles with sms:// style urls

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE with the `relative_urls: false` option enabled and am unable to use links that begin with `sms://`. tinyMCE does not seem to recognize this protocol and therefor doesn't see things beginning with it as an absolute url, it then tacks on to that url. So I may start with `sms://124567` and end with `path/to/my/app/sms://1234567`. Is there a way to provide tinyMCE with the understanding that `sms://` is a valid protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out this question for the answer.

[N2CMS TinyMCE filter_allowed_protocols for skype:{user}?call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425855/n2cms-tinymce-filter-allowed-protocols-for-skypeusercall)

It suggests using the code:

```
<n2 xmlns="http://n2cms.com/schemas/configuration/v3">    
    <edit>
      <tinyMCE enabled="true">
        <settings>
          <add key="convert_urls" value="false" />
        </settings>
      </tinyMCE>
    </edit>
 </n2>
```

> TinyMCE settings should still be in the same place where they always
>   were - in web.config.